Space issues after inserting Diagrams and tables
I am writing a peper in IEEE double column, now my tables are very wide so I have place them in landscape but my space is left unfilled in portrait pages, where as I want to fill the the text which in on the next portrait pages, how I adjust my text so that no space left blank.ss attached
\documentclass[journal,twoside,web]{ieeecolor}
\usepackage{generic}
\usepackage{pdflscape} % Import the package for landscape pages
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks=true}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{alphalph} 
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\markboth{\hskip25pc IEEE TRANSACTIONS AND JOURNALS TEMPLATE}
{Author \MakeLowercase{\textit{et al.}}: Title}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\renewcommand\thesubsectiondis{\AlphAlph{\value{subsection}}}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\caption{Mapping of OPD Indicators}
\label{table}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\begin{tabular}{|p{40pt}|p{100pt}|p{150pt}|p{100pt}|p{210pt}|}
\hline
Sr.No& 
DHIS INSTRUMENT/SOURCE& 
DATA AVAILABLE FROM THE INSTRUMENT&
DHIS2 SOFTWARE FORM&
INDICATORS \\
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{p{600pt}}{\centering OPD Data } \\
data
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab1}
\end{table}


Are the figures/tables floated? If so, what float specifiers are you using?

We need to see the LaTeX code that (a) switches between portrait and landscape mode and (b) generates a representative table.

i have added the code
